# how to get an output message from tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, output

I'm trying to make a quiz app and I have written the following code which is incomplete I am trying to get an output message from the app which gives the answer which the student has written it seems funny but i will do some more stuff on it too. the output I want should be something like this:
the client enters 12
the app shows another box which says your answer is 12
but in this example it is being done for a single answer and it should be performable for more questions too.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import math
import random
window=tk.Tk()
def question():
  window=tk.Tk()
  q1=tk.Label(window, text="enter your question").grid(row=1, column=1)
  e1=tk.Entry(window, text="the number of your answer ").grid(row=2, column=1)
  b1=tk.Button(window, text="exit", command=window.destroy).grid(row=3, column=1)
  window.mainloop()
```

after your helps I have changed my code to this but still have prolems getting a message box or something like that. the updated code is as follows. now the problem is that as soon as I run the code the empty message box opens and does not wait for me to enter some value into the entry

```
def question():
  window=tk.Tk()
  q1=tk.Label(window, text="enter your question")
  e1=tk.Entry(window, text="the number of your answer ")
  b1=tk.Button(window, text="exit", command=window.destroy)
  q1.grid(row=1, column=1)
  e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
  b1.grid(row=3, column=1)
  e1_num=e1.get()
  while e1_num==None:
     pass
  else:
     messagebox.showinfo(e1_num)
  mainloop()
```

Comment: The window will not be run as your not calling the `question` anywhere, maybe highlight on what output you exactly want?

Comment: well I want it to print whatever the client enters this is an simple model of what I want the main one would have many questions I am begginer with tkinter and dont really know what is wrong here

Comment: Have you tried `messagebox` package

Comment: Okay so start by removing the function and that will show a GUI and it's recommended to remove `Entry(...).grid(..)` and split it into two lines like `e1 = Entry(...)` and `e1.grid(...)`. And let me know. You can use `messagebox` to show some messages like correct answer or wrong answer to the user.

Comment: well I tried messagebox but it gave errors maybe I was using it wrong is there any tutorial for it?

Comment: Update your code and maybe I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `e1.insert('0', 'subject')` to insert something into the entry. You can also replace 'subject' with a variable. To delete the contents of the entry you can use `e1.delete(0,END)`

You can get the information from the Entry (e1) and store in it a variable like so: `e1_num = e1.get()`

I hope this helps you :D

Solution to your problem:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

def question():
    window=tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('200x125')
    window.title('Test')

    q1=tk.Label(window, text="Enter your question")
    e1=tk.Entry(window)
    e2=tk.Entry(window)
    b1=tk.Button(window, text="Exit", command=window.destroy)


    def Enter():
        e1_num = e1.get()
        e2.insert('0', e1_num)

    q1.pack()
    e1.pack()
    b2=Button(window, text='Enter', command=Enter)
    b2.pack()
    e2.pack()
    b1.pack()

    window.mainloop()

question()
```

What it will look like:

[image]

Comment: I believe `end-1c` is used with `Text`, why not use `e1.delete(0,END)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure, can you take a look? I'm not on a system right now

Comment: Yeah Sure :) ill take a look

Comment: Ok so (0,END) works for Entry's and ('1.0','end-1c') works for textbox's. Ill make sure to correct my answer.

Comment: so I have changed my code to this but still I cant use message box.                       
  `def question():
      window=tk.Tk()
      q1=tk.Label(window, text="enter your question")
      e1=tk.Entry(window, text="the number of your answer ")
      b1=tk.Button(window, text="exit", command=window.destroy)
      q1.grid(row=1, column=1)
      e1.grid(row=2, column=1)
      b1.grid(row=3, column=1)
      e1_num=e1.get()`

Comment: i have added my solution to my answer :D